# sliding window under a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JPanel and I want it so that whenever a user clicks on it, a sliding window appears just below the panel and giving more information to what is already in the JPanel. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To put something on something, you can use a [JLayeredPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html) or the [zorder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29) thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
http://java-sl.com/tip_slider.html

Comment: nice code +1, that should be answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304017/how-to-add-sexy-on-off-sliders, hmmm reincatnate zoombie,

Comment: hmmm and someone want to live forever `Copyright © 2003-**2010** Stanislav Lapitsky. All Rights Reserved.`

Comment: Next year I will change to 2003-2012:-)

Comment: why waste time, let it at 10 anniversary, then 25.th and 50th. as with wwendings anniversary :-)

Answer (score 0):

The requirements of your question are terrible so we can't give much detail.

If you want to to animation then use a Swing Timer. Each time the timer fires you change the height of the component to make it look likes its sliding.

Comment: sorry if the requirements aren't clear. basically what i want is to have a window that appears at the bottom of the panel when I press on the panel... as simple as that

Comment: Create a window and make it visible. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add a mouselistener to the jpanel, then upon mousepressed add an inner panel, or pull up a different card, or do whatever it is that works for your particular swing layout.