# How to add sexy on/off sliders?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'd like to add an on/off like toggle switch in a Java app. Do I need to build them up from Swing Sliders or is there something closer already?

http://www.premiumpixels.com/freebies/onoff-switches-and-toggles-psd/

http://modmyi.com/forums/iphone-2g-3g-3gs-ipod-touch-1g-2g-3g-new-skins-themes-launches/447951-release-off-slider-lockscreen.html

[image: Apple uses toggle switches of the kind I'm describing in it's Desktop Applications too]

[image: Google uses toggle switches of the kind I'm describing in it's Web Applications too]

Comment: Such a thing does not exist in the standar swing library. Try searching a 3rd party library or make one yourself. I'd use the JCheckBox. IPhone controls are intended for small touchscreens, swing ones are intended for large desktop screens sizes with a mouse.

Answer (score 21):

Just a little example, perhaps it help you.

[image]

```
public class Popup extends JFrame {

    public Popup() {
        setBounds( 100, 100, 300, 120 );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( 3 );
        getContentPane().setLayout( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.LEADING, 10, 10 ) );
        getContentPane().add( new JSwitchBox( "on", "off" ));
        getContentPane().add( new JSwitchBox( "yes", "no" ));
        getContentPane().add( new JSwitchBox( "true", "false" ));
        getContentPane().add( new JSwitchBox( "on", "off" ));
        getContentPane().add( new JSwitchBox( "yes", "no" ));
        getContentPane().add( new JSwitchBox( "true", "false" ));
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Popup().setVisible( true );
            }
        });
    }

    public class JSwitchBox extends AbstractButton{
        private Color colorBright = new Color(220,220,220);
        private Color colorDark = new Color(150,150,150);
        private Color black  = new Color(0,0,0,100);
        private Color white = new Color(255,255,255,100);
        private Color light = new Color(220,220,220,100);
        private Color red = new Color(160,130,130);
        private Color green = new Color(130,160,130);
        private Font font = new JLabel().getFont();
        private int gap = 5;
        private int globalWitdh = 0;
        private final String trueLabel;
        private final String falseLabel;
        private Dimension thumbBounds;
        private Rectangle2D bounds;
        private int max;


        public JSwitchBox(String trueLabel, String falseLabel) {
            this.trueLabel = trueLabel;
            this.falseLabel = falseLabel;
            double trueLenth = getFontMetrics( getFont() ).getStringBounds( trueLabel, getGraphics() ).getWidth();
            double falseLenght = getFontMetrics( getFont() ).getStringBounds( falseLabel, getGraphics() ).getWidth();
            max = (int)Math.max( trueLenth, falseLenght );
            gap =  Math.max( 5, 5+(int)Math.abs(trueLenth - falseLenght ) ); 
            thumbBounds  = new Dimension(max+gap*2,20);
            globalWitdh =  max + thumbBounds.width+gap*2;
            setModel( new DefaultButtonModel() );
            setSelected( false );
            addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e ) {
                    if(new Rectangle( getPreferredSize() ).contains( e.getPoint() )) {
                        setSelected( !isSelected() );
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(globalWitdh, thumbBounds.height);
        }

        @Override
        public void setSelected( boolean b ) {
            if(b){
                setText( trueLabel );
                setBackground( green );
            } else {
                setBackground( red );
                setText( falseLabel );
            }
            super.setSelected( b );
        }
        @Override
        public void setText( String text ) {
            super.setText( text );
        }

        @Override
        public int getHeight() {
            return getPreferredSize().height;
        }

        @Override
        public int getWidth() {
            return getPreferredSize().width;
        }

        @Override
        public Font getFont() {
            return font;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
            g.setColor( getBackground() );
            g.fillRoundRect( 1, 1, getWidth()-2 - 1, getHeight()-2 ,2 ,2 );
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

            g2.setColor( black );
            g2.drawRoundRect( 1, 1, getWidth()-2 - 1, getHeight()-2 - 1, 2,2 );
            g2.setColor( white );
            g2.drawRoundRect( 1 + 1, 1 + 1, getWidth()-2 - 3, getHeight()-2 - 3, 2,2 );

            int x = 0;
            int lx = 0;
            if(isSelected()) {
                lx = thumbBounds.width;
            } else {
                x = thumbBounds.width;
            }
            int y = 0;
            int w = thumbBounds.width;
            int h = thumbBounds.height;

            g2.setPaint( new GradientPaint(x, (int)(y-0.1*h), colorDark , x, (int)(y+1.2*h), light) );
            g2.fillRect( x, y, w, h );
            g2.setPaint( new GradientPaint(x, (int)(y+.65*h), light , x, (int)(y+1.3*h), colorDark) );
            g2.fillRect( x, (int)(y+.65*h), w, (int)(h-.65*h) );

            if (w>14){
                int size = 10;
                g2.setColor( colorBright );
                g2.fillRect(x+w/2-size/2,y+h/2-size/2, size, size);
                g2.setColor( new Color(120,120,120));
                g2.fillRect(x+w/2-4,h/2-4, 2, 2);
                g2.fillRect(x+w/2-1,h/2-4, 2, 2);
                g2.fillRect(x+w/2+2,h/2-4, 2, 2);
                g2.setColor( colorDark );
                g2.fillRect(x+w/2-4,h/2-2, 2, 6);
                g2.fillRect(x+w/2-1,h/2-2, 2, 6);
                g2.fillRect(x+w/2+2,h/2-2, 2, 6);
                g2.setColor( new Color(170,170,170));
                g2.fillRect(x+w/2-4,h/2+2, 2, 2);
                g2.fillRect(x+w/2-1,h/2+2, 2, 2);
                g2.fillRect(x+w/2+2,h/2+2, 2, 2);
            }

            g2.setColor( black );
            g2.drawRoundRect( x, y, w - 1, h - 1, 2,2 );
            g2.setColor( white );
            g2.drawRoundRect( x + 1, y + 1, w - 3, h - 3, 2,2 );

            g2.setColor( black.darker() );
            g2.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON );
            g2.setFont( getFont() );
            g2.drawString( getText(), lx+gap, y+h/2+h/4 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for versatility. I was thinking of just clipping the icons provided, but this is easier to localize.

Comment: +1 for sexiness. But the slider feeling is absent. To immediately try the code mvn install; mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mysimpatico.sexybutton.Popup"
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23278095/SexyButton.zip

Comment: maybe you would [want to answering this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19273548/2853553)

Comment: @oliholz How can I set color for text?

Answer (score 2):

use built-in component JCheckBox.

```
JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox(createImageIcon("off-image.gif", "Click To Turn On"));
cb.setSelectedIcon(createImageIcon("on-image.gif", "Click To Turn Off"));
```

Comment: +1 for re-use :-) just a small beware: you'll need localized icons - but that shouldn't be a big deal

Comment: What do you mean with localized icons? Please share, I'm still learning with java :)

Comment: there are more languages than English (as shown in the pic :)

Answer (score 1):

maybe by using JScrollBar, here is just and incompleted idea, up to you

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Sliders {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel main;
    private JPanel scrollBarPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel sliderPanel;

    public Sliders() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        main = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        final JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 0, 200);
        int height = scrollBar.getPreferredSize().height;
        scrollBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, height));
        scrollBarPanel.add(scrollBar);
        main.add(scrollBarPanel);
        sliderPanel = new JPanel();
        final JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, 128);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(48);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(16);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        sliderPanel.add(slider);
        main.add(sliderPanel);
        frame.add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        scrollBar.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("JScrollBar's current value = " + scrollBar.getValue());
            }
        });
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                System.out.println("JSlider's current value = " + slider.getValue());
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Sliders sliders = new Sliders();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't - you'll have to implement the selection logic (aka: ButtonModel) as well

Comment: @kleopatra hmmm good well, ...., I' lost somewhere, no idea only this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218117/sliding-window-under-a-jpanel/7291620#7291620, and more than illusions could be possible, don't hesitage to update code that I posted,

Comment: +1 interesting. I would have used `JToggleButton` with icons, but `BoundedRangeModel` works in a `new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 1, 0)`.

Comment: @trashgod right, ... or http://java-sl.com/tip_slider.html, but as his endless layzyness as you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218117/sliding-window-under-a-jpanel/7291620#7291620