# Switch Like Interface using JRadioButtons

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

Can anyone please tell me how to make an interface like that which is been shown below.
Right now i'm using two JRadioButton for implementing that task.
My code which i've done is shown below

```
JRadioButton but1 = new JRadioButton("Option 1");
JRadioButton but2 = new JRadioButton("Option 2");

ButtonGroup db=new ButtonGroup();
db.add(but1);
db.add(but2);
```

But how can we make the interface shown in the picture which does the same task that i've done through JRadioButtons.

[image]

Comment: What about using a `JSlider`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- required custom `Icons` and two `JToggleButton`s chained by `ItemListener`
- create `JSlider` with two ranges (required custom painting)
- [great idea by @oliholz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7308818/714968)

Comment: Nice link. I would probably use a `JSlider` with custom painting. Because that already has the "slider feeling" implemented and the logic is already there.

Comment: There's a `BasicSliderUI` example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6996263/230513).