# How to add an on/off sliders in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I found [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304017/how-to-add-sexy-on-off-sliders) but it is in Swing. I want the same thing in SWT.

So how can I make an ON/OFF slider in SWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [opal project](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/) has a [`SwitchButton`](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/SwitchButton) which should be exactly what you are searching for. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

You can use it like this:

```
SwitchButton button = new SwitchButton(shell, SWT.NONE);
button.setTextForSelect("ON");
button.setTextForUnselect("OFF");
```